# Cannot load HTML file with QWebEngineView.setHtml()

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

The solution of my problem is probably very simple but yet out of my understanding. I am trying to load an HTML file into a QWebEngineView with PyQt5. The way I am doing it is:

```
self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.splitter)
html = r"C:\DATI\git\webgis\map.html"
self.webView.setHtml(html)
```

The only thing I get is a string representing the path and name of my HTML file:

> C:\DATI\git\webgis\map.html

My *map.html* looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src=".js/qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        html, body, #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script  src="./js/map.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Strangely (to me at least), if I do `self.webView.setHtml("<html><head></head><body><h1>ciao</h1></body></html>")`, this will render the HTML properly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [setHtml method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setHtml) does exactly what its name suggests: it loads *html content* from a string. What you are trying to do is load a *url*, so for that, you need to use the [load method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#load):

```
url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(r"C:\DATI\git\webgis\map.html")
self.webView.load(url)
```